# dynamically creating checkboxes from a list of checkboxes in tkinter python 2.7

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

I am trying to create new checkboxes from a list of checkboxes but in a new frame. The newly created checkboxes however act like radiobuttons when created at the same time. Here is the code (only for the function creating the boxes)

```
def printcheckbuttons():
    val=StringVar()#checkboxlist is a list of checkbox widgets
    for x in range (len(checkboxlist)):
        for ki in checkboxlist:
            if ki.var.get() != 'null':
                sale=Checkbutton(frameright,text=ki.var.get()[0:],variable=val,onvalue=ki.var.get(),offvalue='null')
                sale.val=val
                saletracker.append(sale)#saletracker is a list to track selected checkboxes in checkboxlist ant post them to a second frame
                sale.pack(anchor=NW)           
                checkboxlist.remove(ki)
                ki.destroy()
                print 'checkboxlist 1',checkboxlist
   destroyboxes(checkboxlist)#destroys and removes all checkboxes in checkbuttonlist
   print 'checkboxlist',checkboxlist
   print "saletracker ", saletracker
```

Comment: It looks like you are just duplicating a checkbox, then destroying the original. What's the point in that? Why don't you just keep and re-use the original?

Comment: The second set is a subset of the original set allowing multiple selections from different searches to be selected. The issue was with my having the same instance of StringVar() for multiple checkboxes. The variable is better created within the loop for proper performance

Answer (score 0):

You are giving them all the same value for `variable` attribute -- they each need to each have their own instance of a `StringVar`. You need to move creation of `val` inside the loop so that each checkbutton gets a unique `StringVar`.

You also have the problem that, after creating the new variable, you aren't setting it to a value. When creating checkbuttons, you need to make sure that the associated variable is set to either the on value or the off value.

Comment: Works well but there is still an issue of a  'ghost' button that has no text. just a square. However it has no variable value thus it does not affect functioning of the program negatively when commiting to the database

Comment: @gichmain: there is nothing I can do with that information. It's not a bug or limitation in tkinter, it's a bug in your code. Without seeing the code it s impossible to know what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with the code above. First the creation of the variable val ought to be for every checkbox created and failing to initialse the boxes to one of the values. After making these two corrections the code worked fine.

```
def printcheckbuttons():
    for x in range (len(checkboxlist)):

        for ki in checkboxlist:
        #val=StringVar()
            if ki.var.get() != 'null':
                val=StringVar()
                sale=Checkbutton(frameright,text=ki.var.get()[0:],variable=val,onvalue=ki.var.get(),offvalue='null')
                sale.val=val
                saletracker.append(sale)
                sale.pack(anchor=NW)
                sale.deselect()           
                checkboxlist.remove(ki)
                ki.destroy()
                print 'checkboxlist 1',checkboxlist
   destroyboxes(checkboxlist)
   print 'checkboxlist',checkboxlist
   print "saletracker ", saletracker
```